# Django ManyToManyField Persistence Fails

Tags: django

I have a simple Django 3.1.0 app I need to create in order to assign Tasks with Tags (or assign tags into tasks).

**My Model**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tags = models.ForeignKey('Tag', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Tag(models.Model):

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="No Tag")
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Task')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "tags"
```

**My Form**

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['user', 'task', 'tags']
        template_name = 'tasks.html'
    
    tags = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Tag.objects.values().all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
```

**My View**

```
def main(request):
    model = Task.objects.values().all()
    form = TaskForm()
    con = {'context': list(model), 'form': form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = TaskForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          obj = form.save(commit=False)
          form.save_m2m()
          return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render(request, "tasks.html", con)
```

The migrations are successfull, and with the above code, the view shows a checkbox list with the fetched tags, but the problem is that when I hit Submit on the form, the values are not saved/written on the database but the page reloads successfully.

However, if I turn the following:

```
          obj = form.save(commit=False)
          form.save_m2m()
```

into

```
          form.save(commit=True)
          #form.save_m2m()
```

the values are written only from the fields 'user', 'task' - without the 'tags'

It's also funny that what fetches back on the webpage as values of the tags is in the shape of:

```
[checkbox] {'id': 1, 'tag': 'aks'}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE after a comment below:**

As Abdul Aziz suggested, I had to remove the *values()* from the **queryset**. But after that , to make it work, I had to add also:

In the model:

```
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="No Tags")
```

and then refer to that one in the form and Vue template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `ForeignKey` set to the `Tag` model on your `Task` model, when you actually want a `ManyToMany` relationship between them. Remove the foreign key and set a related_name to the `ManyToManyField` in the `Tag` model like so:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Tag(models.Model):

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="No Tag")
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Task', related_name="tags")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "tags"
```

Also in your form you have:

```
tags = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Tag.objects.values().all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple()
)
```

Why are you using `values` here? Remove it:

```
tags = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Tag.objects.all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple()
)
```

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: You are right, i needed to remove the values there! It worked, after i added some things, for which i will edit my question. Thanks.